# Typical auth process with laravel passport

Tags: oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3

**I'm creating an API with laravel 5.3**. ***"laravel passport"*** got my attention these days. previously i used `tymon/JWT` package to authenticate my users. but **i wants to use laravel passport** for my new peoject.

**So i can use my API for my mobile and web both client.**

So ho can i **do typical authentication with email and password** in laravel passport for web client.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Password grant token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#password-grant-tokens).
But in short you send some form_data to `/oauth/token` route and get an `access_token` in return and with that token you make your API requests.